# What is the best way for creating a greendao v3 session in a DAO module?

Tags: java, android, greendao, greendao-generator

I have my project divided in three modules (multilayered architecture):
App (where i have my activities)
BusinessLogic
DAO (where i am using greenDAO version 3)

And i need to know the best way for opening a DB session from the DAO layer, where i dont have any activity (in this moment i am sending the activiy like a parameter).

Articulo.class:

```
@Id
Long id;

@NotNull
String nombre;


public Articulo (){}



@Generated(hash = 742341383)
public Articulo(Long id, @NotNull String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

App.class:

```
public static final boolean ENCRYPTED = false;

private DaoSession daoSession;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, ENCRYPTED ? "notes-db-encrypted" : "notes-db");
    Database db = ENCRYPTED ? helper.getEncryptedWritableDb("super-secret") : helper.getWritableDb();
    daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
}

public DaoSession getDaoSession() {
    return daoSession;
}
```

ArticuoBL.class (businessLogic)  HERE IS MY PROBLEM, WHERE I WANT TO GET THE SESSION

```
private ArticuloDao artDAO;

public ArticuloBL(){}


public void crearArticulo(Activity act){
    Articulo art = new Articulo();
    art.setId(3l);
    art.setNombre("New Article");

    DaoSession daoSession = ((App) act.getApplication()).getDaoSession();
    artDAO = daoSession.getArticuloDao();

    artDAO.insertInTx(art);
}
```

Thanks